# How to register Ef core db context with Castle windsor?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, castle-windsor, castle

I " ve got a project under .net core. I want to register Ef Core Context with Castle windosr  But I couldn 't find a solution to EfCore Wireup context in .net core. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this , first you need to know that you have a Context that has a DbContextOptionsBuilder parameter that has a DbContextOptionsBuilder parameter if you have added these constructor , you need to register this too , and now the code I " ve written below makes you less self - sufficient to use the OnConfiguring method.

```
   public static class DbContextFactoryBuilder
{
    public static IDbContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        var result = new MyDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and code for register in castle.

```
container.Register(Component.For<MyDbContext>().UsingFactoryMethod(c => DbContextFactoryBuilder.Create(@"---your connection string---")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public MyContext (string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(this.connectionString);
    }
}

Component.For<MyContext>().DependsOn(Property.ForKey<string>().Eq("your connection string")));
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but i want configure db context in .net core and your solution not work in .net core because parameterize constructor in ef core different  with entity framework dbContext parameterize constructor
amir amini 's solution worked for me great

Comment: @d7saee, I know that this is about ef core, and it works in .net core! DbContext in ef core has two constructors, one public with `DbContextOptionsBuilder` shown in different answer and one protected without any parameters as well. So in the end you may create your context without any need to pass `DbContextOptionsBuilder`, because your custom constructor will implicitly call the default one in the base class.